# Downloading Map on Collector for ArcGIS

Tags: web-mapping, download, arcgis-collector, iphone

I know this will sound like a foolish question once I find out what I'm doing wrong but here goes:

I had downloaded an outdated version of my data collection map onto Collector, but I need to switch it out for the more current version. After deleting the content of the previous map I tried to download the newer version, but to no avail! Its not that the download didn't work, its just that there was no download option. I tried looking this problem up online, but I couldn't find any similar cases (which lead me to believe I'm probably doing something stupid). Would this be a problem with my ArcGIS account or my iPhone that I am downloading the map onto?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your data source has the option to download the data is enabled. Either in AGOL (if not you will have to upload a new service by overwriting the existing and check the option to download/extract) or if this is a service feature on a server be sure in the service capabilities settings the extract box is checked.

Comment: I'm still working with the settings, but it doesn't seem to be working... Where would I find an option to enable download/extract?

Comment: is your data being hosted on AGOL or a server?

Comment: I'm using AGOL to export my data.

Comment: If your using AGOL then find the feature layer item and select it, navigate to settings and scroll down to "Export Data"

Comment: The problem is fixed! I had to go into the Web Map and check Enable Offline Mode in the "More details" section. Thanks for the help!

Comment: please mark question as answered if that helped so other users can benefit

Comment: @Joe you didn't answer his Q. The issue was in offline mode disable. He solved it himself

Answer (score 1):

The problem was found in the Map editor in ArcGIS Online. By going to About -> More Details... -> Settings and checking the Enable Offline Mode option.